# Specifying a condition for a joined table in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to sort a list of pods based on when a user joined them.  The relationship between user and pod is managed by a join table called pod_users.

So I have:

```
Pod.rb
has_many :pod_users, dependent: :delete_all
has_many :users, through: :pod_users

User.rb
has_many :pod_users
has_many :pods, through: :pod_users

Pod_user.rb
belongs_to :pod
belongs_to :user
```

When a user joins a pod, a record is updated in pod_users with a timestamp.  I want to order the list of pods that a user belongs to based on that created_at timestamp.

Here's what I've tried based on the instructions for [specifying conditions on joined tables here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html):

```
@pods = @user.pods.joins(:pod_users).where(pod_users: {user_id: @user.id}).order("pod_users.created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page])
```

I've tried different versions.  I've also tried:

```
@pods = @user.pods.joins(:pod_users).order("pod_users.created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page])
```

But then I get duplicates because pods have multiple users and when I do the pod_users join, those additional records get returned.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: I haven't done this before but can you try: has_many :pods, -> { group("id")}, through: :pod_users   -if that doesn't work, the problem is you need to group_by the pod.id to prevent duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `.joins(:pod_users)` and it'll work right away. Since you have `has_many :pods, through: :pod_users`, rails already adds pod_users to the sql query as a join when you do `@user.pods`. If you wanna check this out, do `@user.pods.to_sql` in the console.

Your stuff should work if you do:

```
@pods = @user.pods.order("pod_users.created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page])
```

Comment: Oh man.  So simple and yet I spent hours trying to figure that out.  Thank you!  It worked.